# Accessing session data in other method in same controller is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-variables

I have a function that fetch data from model and store that data in session variable :

```
public function fetchData() {
   $somedata = $this->some_model->some_function();
   $this->session->set_userdata('mydata',$somedata);
}
```

Now If I access the session in same method and print then it works but when I access this session variable in other method then it doesn't work.

```
public function showData() {
   $mydata = $this->session->userdata('mydata');
   print_r($mydata); // it prints nothing
}
```

When I print session in showData() method then it prints only user detail :

```
Array
(
[session_id] => 9c7bc7a7a8acad514d4ece2c841c1403
[ip_address] => 192.168.0.115
[user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
[last_activity] => 1416898254
[user_data] => 
[user] => testuser
[currentUser] => testuser
[userID] => 1
[email_address] => testuser@gmail.com
[first_name] => Test
[last_name] => User
[logged] => 1
[account_type] => admin
[currentUserName] => Test user
)
```

Of course I have setup the session in autoload.php to load by default and also tried to load in constructor but nothing is working.

Can somebody tell me why this is happening ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if you are unsetting the session data.

Comment: I checked, I am not unsetting the session data anywhere.

Comment: session library included? also check your $somedata has values

Comment: Try `print_r($this->session);` and see what you get.

Comment: yes I have included the library in autoload.php and also in constructor but nothing is working.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola : Yes when I print this shows the default session data like login detail but doesn't print the fetched data.

Comment: Update your question by showing the result of `print_r($this->session);`

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola: I tried on chrome but same data is displaying.

Comment: I found that issue is occurring when we are storing large data.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola: But what when we store in first function and it shows all the data. I think storing large data is not a issue.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola : I must tell you one thing that this is happening when I change db. Like when I use one db then it shows all the data but again when I change the other db (which contains the same data) then it doesn't show.

Comment: As CI Documentation says they dont use `Native PHP Session`. So you have to do something like this to use `Native PHP Session` : http://www.moreofless.co.uk/using-native-php-sessions-with-codeigniter/

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola: You were right. It was a issue due to large data storing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by storing session in db.

To hold large data I use a database (see "Saving Session Data to a Database" in http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html).

This saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

You're using this command:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');
```

But this command is only used when you want to **add one value at a time**, and there's nothing saying that you can use one value/row as array, so I recommend you use the:

```
// pass the array to userdata, and not one value containing an array.
$this->session->set_userdata('array_value');
```

It'll be better to understand/read your code. And it seems you're trying to output the **entirely array**, right?
It's simple:

```
print_r($this->session->all_userdata()); // prints all userdata
```

and it will return an associative array like this one:

```
Array
(
    [session_id] => 4a5a5dca22728fb0a84364eeb405b601
    [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7;
    [last_activity] => 1303142623
)
```

But of course, with the associatives you defined. And if you want to print just one row, use:

```
// print one row, i.e: 'session_id', 'ip_address'.
print_r($this->session->userdata('associative_value_you_defined'));
```

For further information, access [CodeIgniter Session Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html).

Comment: Yes you are right but I had tried this too to print all user data but only login detail were printing and when I found that this was the issue due to storing large data, I saved the session in db and now all is well.

Answer (score 0):

This is coming late but i feel it is the right answer and it will help someone with the same problem.

Access one variable this way:

> $data = $this->session->userdata('mydata');

Then:

> echo $data['last_name']; //accessing the last name variable

To print the whole array, just do:

> $data = $this->session->all_userdata();

Then:

> echo $data;